# Construct a matrix transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

consider
$\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ where $A$ is the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & -2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

construct a real matrix $P$ such that the change of coordinates $x=Py$ transforms our real equation to

$\frac{dy}{dt}=By$ where $B$ is the matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then solve explicity for $y$ and evaluate the solution in terms of our original $x=Py$

My Solution so far...

I have diagonalized both $A$ and $B$ and got the following matrices respectively
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 &\sqrt{2} & 0) \\
        0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and for $B$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
the eigenvectors for $A$ make the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1+\sqrt{2} & -1-\sqrt{2} \\
        0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the eigenvectors for $B$ make the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus the determinant of the eigenvector matrix for $B$ is $0$...I am now stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your eigenvalues (for both $A$ and $B$) should be $1$ and $\pm i\sqrt{2}$. Since you have three distinct eigenvalues, the eigenvectors of either matrix are guaranteed to be linearly independent, and thus constitute a basis.
(By necessity, the eigenvectors corresponding to the complex eigenvalues must be complex.)

If $A=S_1\Lambda S_1^{-1}$ and $B=S_2\Lambda S_2^{-1}$, then $B=S_2S_1^{-1}AS_1S_2^{-1}$. This means that you get the desired transformation $P=S_1S_2^{-1}$, and with some luck this will be a real matrix (both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are complex).

Comment: W it is still the case that S_2 has a determinant of 0 therefore we cant invert

Comment: do you have any other suggestions for the method as we cant invert S2

Comment: @Jay: $S_2$ is invertible, as I explained (there are three distinct eigenvalues, which guarantees three linearly independent eigenvectors). The reason why you only found one eigenvector was that you used $\pm \sqrt{2}$ instead of the true eigenvalues $\pm i\sqrt{2}$.